# In bash script, how to check a file is a perl script?

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I have a bunch of files under a directory. how can I check all of them and make sure if it is a perl script or not?(they don't have .pl in the filename)

Answer (score 2):

Check the shebang

```
head -n 1 script | grep perl
```

Normally most command line scripts contain a shebang ie something like

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

They're not required if you are calling the script like this

```
perl script
```

but if you want to call them as system command they help.

Comment: This is a UUOC, just do `head -n 1 script`.

Comment: More succinctly perhaps `grep -m1 ^ * | grep perl` but this doesn't seem to work with *BSD `grep` (or at last Mac OSX Yosemite).

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot rely on there being a valid [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) either, you might pass them to `perl -c`.

```
for f in *; do
    perl -c "$f" 2>/dev/null && echo "$f is Perl"
done
```

If you want properly machine-readable output, maybe switch the `echo` to `printf '%s\0' "$f"` so you can pass it to `xargs -0` and friends.

The obvious flaw with this is that a Perl script with an error in it will be reported as not being (valid) Perl.

Comment: Is a perl script with an error really a perl script though ? Also +1 as none of my perl scripts are executable and so do no have a shebang line.

Comment: If you have a bunch of Perl scripts and make some edits and make a mistake, it is rather problematic that the behavior changes just because of a simple typo (let's say you are doing iterative development, and some part of the iteration relies on the output from this script) -- if you require it to be more robust, maybe make a number of additional probes for fragments of each file which doesn't pass `perl -c` and decide that it's probably Perl after all if a majority passes the check. You have to be careful about how you extract fragments, though.

Comment: Explicitly adding a shebang by routine might be the best long-term solution.

Comment: yep, or simply adding an extension.

Comment: @123 That sort of sucks; adding an explicit extension means you can't change your mind and refactor the script to a Python script, or a `sed` one-liner, or whatever. (Or well, you can, but then the extension will be wrong, too; not a happier situation than you started with.)

Answer (score 0):

```
find ./ -type f -exec egrep -I -l '^use strict;|^use warnings;|^sub |my \$|my \%|my \@|\->{' {} + 2>&1 \
| egrep -v 'README|\.git|\.zsh$|.sh$' \
| xargs file | grep 'ASCII' \
| awk '{print $1}' \
| sed 's/:$//'
```

not perfect but this will find most files with relatively modern Perl5 code in them

Comment: You misspelled `strict`. The requirement for no indentation on some of the keywords is somewhat dubious.

Comment: Also the `find` is rather useless when `grep` has an `-r` flag, though if you refactored the `find` to e.g. filter out the files you separately remove later, that could be useful.

Comment: "You misspelled strict." 

thank you, fixed 

not sure what you mean by no indentation on "use strict" being dubious :) I checked a large body of code written by many people over 15 years and all "use strict"-s were not indented

Answer (score -1):

Since they do not have the extension, try this:

```
find /path/to/directory/ -type f | while read line; do if file -b "$line" | grep -i perl -q; then echo "$line is a perl file"; fi; done
```

Comment: Care to explain the downvote ? I have tested this on my system and its working properly.

Comment: I didn't downvote but `file` returns `ASCII English text` for my perl files.

Comment: try for a specfic perl file and run the command **file -b <perl file>**, what is the output

Comment: I did, it says `ASCII English text`, note that i do not have a shebang directive at the top.

Comment: then try adding the shebang and check, may be the command checks for shebang in the files